# jquery hide class element when detect certain string in url

Tags: jquery

I would like to detect if the domain(the part befor .com) contains string "extraordinaire", then hide content inside the class element "hide"
e.g.

```
www.xxxextraordinaire.com
if {module_pageaddress} contains "extraordinaire" 
then clear all content inside the <div class="hide"></div>
```

else if, do nothing

the css hiden is notworking :(

Comment: Try `jQuery(function ($) {
    if (/extraordinaire\.com/.test(window.location.href)) {
        $('.hide').hide()
    }
})`

Answer (score 1):

You can get domain name by `window.location.hostname`

Then set condition and hide element, like here:

```
if(domain.indexOf('extraordinaire') >= 0) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("hide")[0].style.visibility = "hidden";
}
```

You can see it on this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/uUr7v/)

Comment: You'd likely want to set the `display` to `none` vs. visibility which would hold the space.

Comment: thanks, but the css hide is notworking, i dont know why, could you please try clear all content inside? thanks

Comment: Then you can use `$(".hide").html("");`, you can see it on this [updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/uUr7v/1/)

Answer (score 1):

debute has already answered perfectly, but if you need the JQuery version:

```
    var domain = window.location.hostname;
if(domain.indexOf('extraordinaire') >= 0) {
    $(".hide").css('visibility' , "hidden");

}
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/web_developer_888/9P5qe/)

Comment: thanks, but the css hide is notworking, i dont know why, could you please try clear all content inside? thanks